# Pass Information from AlertDialog to parent Fragment

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, android-alertdialog

I am trying to pass Information from my AlertDialog to the parent Fragment it is on. But as soon as you klick the positive button, the app will crash.
I dont really know what todo anymore already read many Posts and articles but could not find the Problem. 
Would be great if you could help me out.(Im a beginner)

Here is the Error I get with the first Problem in Code and the second commented.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 20682
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.test.SchulfachDialog$SchulfachDialogListener.applyTexts(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.SchulfachDialog$1.onClick(SchulfachDialog.java:39)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

here is my code for the alert Dialog:

```
builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Add new subject")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                    listener.applyTexts(name); // Problem 1: when positiv Button is pushed this line causes a crash
                }
            });

    editTextName = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

    return builder.create();
}
```

this is the applyTexts which I override in the fragments Code:

```
public interface SchulfachDialogListener{
        void applyTexts(String name);

    }
}


@Override public void applyTexts(String name) {
            test = name;
    }

}
```

I also have this block in which the 2 commented lines cause a crash when clicking on the button which starts the alert Dialog:

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (SchulfachDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
   //        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+
  //                 "must implement SchulfachDialogListener");  
        }
    }
```

Comment: listener.applyTexts(name); here listener is null. share the code from where (your parent Fragment) u set your listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** To pass data from an alert dialog to a parent fragment, the easier way is let the dialog extends DialogFragment. Then using `setTargetFragment` and `setTargetFragment` to send data between them.

Because you do not post parent fragment code, so I assume here is xml and java code of your parent fragment.

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SchulfachDialogListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button btnShowAlertDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.button_show_alert_dialog);
        btnShowAlertDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SchulfachDialog dialog = new SchulfachDialog();
                dialog.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, 0);
                dialog.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTexts(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Alert Dialog"
        android:id="@+id/button_show_alert_dialog"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let the alert dialog extends DialogFragment.

```
public class SchulfachDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText editTextName;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(requireActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_schulfach, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Add new subject")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                        SchulfachDialogListener listener = (SchulfachDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
                        listener.applyTexts(name);
                    }
                });
        editTextName = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```